# SSD not detected Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS after inserting in SSD Slot

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, hard-drive, dell, ssd

I have two RAMs and 1TB harddisk. Now i installed 512gb SSD in SSD Slot but its not showing

```
pc:~$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       12008232     5105172      151980      473800     6751080     6103032
Swap:      12582904       63348    12519556

pc:~$ free -g -h -t
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           11Gi       4.8Gi       146Mi       455Mi       6.5Gi       5.9Gi
Swap:          11Gi        86Mi        11Gi
Total:         23Gi       4.9Gi        12Gi
```

**pc:~$ lsblk**

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1    7:1    0   9.6M  1 loop /snap/canonical-livepatch/229
loop2    7:2    0   9.6M  1 loop /snap/canonical-livepatch/235
loop3    7:3    0 118.2M  1 loop /snap/core/15511
loop4    7:4    0 105.8M  1 loop /snap/core/15925
loop5    7:5    0  55.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/2785
loop6    7:6    0  55.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/2790
loop7    7:7    0  63.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/1974
loop8    7:8    0  73.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/858
loop9    7:9    0  63.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/2015
loop10   7:10   0  73.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/864
loop11   7:11   0 218.4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/90
loop12   7:12   0 349.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/140
loop13   7:13   0 218.4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/93
loop14   7:14   0 349.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143
loop15   7:15   0 485.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/120
loop16   7:16   0 485.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/126
loop17   7:17   0  81.3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop18   7:18   0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop19   7:19   0 260.7M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32
loop20   7:20   0 289.8M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/35
loop21   7:21   0 479.7M  1 loop /snap/netbeans/80
loop22   7:22   0 482.3M  1 loop /snap/netbeans/84
loop23   7:23   0    46M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/638
loop24   7:24   0  40.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19993
loop25   7:25   0  40.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/20092
loop26   7:26   0  65.2M  1 loop /snap/sublime-text/118
loop27   7:27   0  63.9M  1 loop /snap/sublime-text/122
loop28   7:28   0  29.1M  1 loop /snap/voxcraft-viz/39
loop29   7:29   0  12.3M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/959
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0   931G  0 part /
```

**pc:~$ df -h**

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            5.7G     0  5.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.2G  3.7M  1.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       916G  771G   99G  89% /
tmpfs           5.8G  317M  5.5G   6% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop2      9.7M  9.7M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/235
/dev/loop3      119M  119M     0 100% /snap/core/15511
/dev/loop5       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2785
/dev/loop1      9.7M  9.7M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/229
/dev/loop4      106M  106M     0 100% /snap/core/15925
/dev/loop10      74M   74M     0 100% /snap/core22/864
/dev/loop6       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2790
/dev/loop18      92M   92M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop16     486M  486M     0 100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/126
/dev/loop7       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1974
/dev/loop8       74M   74M     0 100% /snap/core22/858
/dev/loop11     219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/90
/dev/loop14     350M  350M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143
/dev/loop12     350M  350M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/140
/dev/loop9       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/2015
/dev/loop19     261M  261M     0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32
/dev/loop17      82M   82M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
/dev/loop15     486M  486M     0 100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/120
/dev/loop13     219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/93
/dev/loop20     290M  290M     0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/35
/dev/loop21     480M  480M     0 100% /snap/netbeans/80
/dev/loop22     483M  483M     0 100% /snap/netbeans/84
/dev/loop23      46M   46M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/638
/dev/loop29      13M   13M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/959
/dev/loop24      41M   41M     0 100% /snap/snapd/19993
/dev/loop25      41M   41M     0 100% /snap/snapd/20092
/dev/loop28      30M   30M     0 100% /snap/voxcraft-viz/39
/dev/loop27      64M   64M     0 100% /snap/sublime-text/122
/dev/loop26      66M   66M     0 100% /snap/sublime-text/118
/dev/sda1       511M   44M  468M   9% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.2G   56K  1.2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

I need only some softwares like IntelliJ IDEA IDE to run on SSD. Thats y i bought SSD. But SSD not showing up in the list. Im using DELL inspiron. What to do?

- Edit:
  I updated *BIOS* and reinserted the SSD again. Now SSD is shown in *BIOS* but not in my Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS *Disk Usage Analyzer* or *Disks* gui. I think i need to convert from `RAID ON` (currently selected) to `AHCI` (under SATA Operation-Set operating mode of integrated SATA hard drive controller).
  But when i changed and try saving it in *BIOS*, it shows warning that *OS* maybe corrupted. How to change it without corrupting ubuntu?
- Note: Also Im not sure whether converting `RAID ON` to `AHCI` will make SSD show in Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Comment: Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: See the Filesystem Hierarcy Standard at `https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml`, or read `man hier`.
  
It explains where things go.

Comment: What PC do you have, and what SSD did you install?

Comment: DELL inspiron 15 3501 and SSD is "Crucial P3 500GB PCIe 3.0 3D NAND NVMe M.2 SSD, up to 3500MB/s"